# From file to list

Tags: python, list, file

Hello guys what I am trying to do is to read a file with digits put like this example(below) to a `list[1,2,3,4]` :

> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3
>
> 4
>
> 5

Im doing this in class. I tried to do this without my class like this:

```
 def velocity():
 items = []
 with open('smhi.txt') as input:
     for line in input:
         items.extend(line.strip().split())
 return items
```

When I print items I get `["1,","2","3","4"]`

Answer (score 1):

you need to convert your numbers to `int`,and you can use a list comprehension as following but,note that as you define the list inside the function its in local name space so you couldn't access it outside of the function!so you need to return your list :

```
def velocity():
   with open('smhi.txt') as input:
       my_list=[int(line) for line in input if line.strip()]
   return my_list
```

result :

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: I get the error TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'

Comment: seems `[int(line) for line in f if line.strip()]` would be enough.

Comment: @Kasra I only get [] as output

Comment: If i have it in my class like this  (I want this list to my main program)                                                                                                       def velocity(self,):
    with open('smhi.txt') as input:
       my_list=[int(line.strip()) for line in input if line.strip()]
       return my_list:

Comment: @Pellegrino how you get that result!!! note that as you define the list inside the function its in local name space so you couldn't access it outside of the function!!

Comment: @Kasra It worked as you said, thank you very much! My problem now is to do it in my class and get that list to my main program

Comment: @Pellegrino glad that hear about that, about your new problem its hard to imagine what you mean without seeing your code!

Comment: Can we chat Kasra? :) Im kinda new here, so I dont know if Im allowed to change the thread, don't think so though hehe :P

Comment: @Pellegrino sorry i need to go now! :)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yes ! fixed!

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly convert the datatype of digits to integer.

```
with open('file') as f:
    print([int(i) for i in f if i.strip().isdigit()])
```

OR

```
with open('file') as f:
    print([int(j) for i in f for j in i.strip()])
```

OR

```
with open('file') as f:
    print([int(line) for line in f if line.strip()])
```